# Formatting Y field values in telerik html chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Is there any way to format DataFieldY on telerik RadHtml Charts?

I tried following code;

```
RadHtmlChart3.PlotArea.Series[0].DataFieldY = String.Format("{0:0.00}","veriyuzde");
```

which produced no change.

Also, I used this

```
RadHtmlChart3.PlotArea.YAxis.LabelsAppearance.DataFormatString = "N";
```

but it only formats the labels when I want to format the values.

Am I missing something or is it impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [chart structure diagram](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-structure-elements.html).  I think what you want to update is the "Series Item Label", right?

You can do that by

```
chart.PlotArea.YAxis.LabelsAppearance.DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}";
```

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that only works on formatting axis labels not series item labels. It turns label number "20" to "20.00" but does nothing to the series item labels. They are still like "2.627666" and several more digits